# I used anaconda3 python 3 run the following code appears, NameError: name 'TurleControl' is not defined.How to fix?

Tags: pi-3b+

```
import turtle
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import*

class TurtleControl(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,turtle):
        super(TurleControl.self).__init__()
        self.turtle=turtle

        self.left_btn=QPushButton("Left".self)
        self.right_btn=QPusButton("Right",self)
        self.move_btn=QPushButton("Move",self)
        self.distance_spin=QSpinBox()

        self.controlsLayout=QGriDlayout()
        self.controlsLayout=addWidget(self.left_btn,0,0)
        self.controlsLayout=addWidget(self.right_btn,0,1)
        self.controlsLayout=addWidget(self.distance_spin,1,0)
        self.controlsLayout=addWidget(self.move_btn,1,1)
        self.setLayout(self.controlsLayout)

        self.distance_spin.setRange(0,100)
        self.distance_spin.setSingleStep(5)
        self.distance_spin.setValue(20)

#set up turtle
window=turtle.Screen()
babbage=turtle.Turtle()

#Create  qt application

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
control_window=TurtleControl(babbage)
control_window.show()

#Enter QT application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message looks clear to me: it's a typo

```
super(TurleControl.self).__init__()
```

should be

```
super(TurtleControl.self).__init__()
```

(Note the missing 't' in your code).

Comment: Thank you, I am modified and then try again again with other errors as follows:NameError: name 'QPusButton' is not defined

Comment: That would be a new issue and you have to start a new question. It is not Pi related and Raspberry SE is actually not the right place to ask these questions. Make sure you give full code *and* full error messages